Custom Headers for ResponseStatusException
When implementing a RateLimitException I'm facing issues that custom headers are not applied in response.
public class QuotaExceededException extends ResponseStatusException {

    final Long retryAfter;
    
    public QuotaExceededException(Long retryAfterSeconds) {
        super(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
        retryAfter = retryAfterSeconds;
    }
    
    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        var headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.RETRY_AFTER, String.valueOf(retryAfter));
        headers.set("X-RateLimit-Remaining", "0");
        headers.set("X-RateLimit-Reset", String.valueOf(retryAfter));
        return headers;
    } 
}

Anyway the getHeaders() is never called.
I've had a look and even Spring standard exception are implementing it like this. Is there any way to check why this method is not called?

what spring boot version are you using?
